# Compressing(zip) List of files with ZipOutPutStream Java

Tags: java, xml, rest, bytearrayoutputstream, zipoutputstream

I`m trying to compress a list of Xml converted on Strings, save them in only one zip file and returning as a body of a POST on restful. But everytime I save the file I get the error "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged".

```
protected ByteArrayOutputStream zip(Map<String, String> mapConvertedXml) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    try {
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> current : mapConvertedXml.entrySet()){

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(current.getKey() + ".xml");
            entry.setSize(current.getValue().length());
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            zos.write(current.getValue().getBytes());
            zos.flush();
        }

        zos.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return baos;
}
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: did you try checking the zip file before transferring to network?

Comment: What is the charset you are using? Because the lenght of the String does NOT always match the lenght of its byte array.

Comment: @nandsito no I didn`t, is there a function for that on ZipOutputStream?

Comment: @Boschi I`m dealing with a list of xml as String(This is the list Map<String, String> mapConvertedXml) on charset UTF-8.

Comment: by the end of the method `baos` will be a in-memory zip file. Try dumping it into a file somewhere

Comment: Use the byte array length instead of the String length.

Comment: Hey, guys thanks for the help, but I found the issue. Since I`m using restful to return the zip, IDK but the REST call was returning the file as base64 string. I had to make the conversion before saving.

Answer (score 0):

To test your zip file please save it temporarily in your filesystem and open it manualy.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathToZipFile);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
```

Then, you can use something like that to construct your Rest Server and return your file.

```
public static Response getFileLast(@Context UriInfo ui, @Context HttpHeaders hh) {
    Response response = null;
    byte[] sucess = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = getYourFile();
    sucess = baos.toByteArray();
    if(sucess!=null) {
        response = Response.ok(sucess, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("content-disposition","attachment; filename = YourFileName").build();
    } else {
        response = Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(new Error("Error downloading file.")).build();
    }

    return response;
}
```

You can test this [Advanced Rest Client](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNjP6Vi-3SAhVs5IMKHSDuBH8QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&usg=AFQjCNEo489FdO7M0eVz4c9u475vROBbXQ&sig2=doDOOMl3A9LXNnIzKG2Cag) for example.